# Cannot list all LDAP attributes using C#

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, ldapconnection

I am trying to get a list of all attributes for a given LDAP entry, with the following code:

```
LdapConnection conn = GetOpenLdapConnection();

string filter = "(uid=" + user + ")";
SearchRequest search = new SearchRequest(LDAP_BASE, filter, SearchScope.Subtree, "*");
SearchResponse resp = conn.SendRequest(search) as SearchResponse;

SearchResultEntry entry = resp.Entries[0];
Console.WriteLine(entry.DistinguishedName);
foreach (string attr in entry.Attributes.AttributeNames)
    Console.WriteLine("Name:" + attr);

conn.Dispose();
```

However, this only prints one attribute name: "uid".  I'm confused as to why this is not returning all of the attributes that I can clearly see using an LDAP browser (browsing the same entry for the given `user` as the code is attempting to retrieve).

Honestly, I don't care to see all the attributes; I know the names of the ones I want to retrieve, but even if I replace `new SearchRequest(..., "*")` with `new SearchRequest(..., "attr1", "attr2", "etc.")`, the only one I can seem to retrieve is `"uid"`.  Is there something obvious here I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, in my function `GetOpenLdapConnection()`, I needed to set the `AuthType` for the `LdapConnection` to `Basic`.  Now everything seems to be working correctly.  Hope this helps someone else.